# NODE JS ERROR NPM INSTALL!

Tags: node.js, npm

При выполнении команды "npm install" в терминале - получаю следующее:

```
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! package.json ENOENT, open '/home/www/app.luckyplay.su/package.json'
npm ERR! package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-042stab120.16
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /home/www/app.luckyplay.su
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.29
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! path /home/www/app.luckyplay.su/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOPACKAGEJSON
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/www/app.luckyplay.su/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: проверьте, что у вас есть файл `package.json`

Comment: Да, есть........

Comment: проверьте, что вы запускаете `npm install` в правильной директории, в той в которой `package.json`

Comment: в правильной директории запускаю. Сейчас показывает это: 
npm ERR! 404 Not Found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 'angular/http' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'Angular2'
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, or http url, or git url.

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.